# How to replace back button in react-native-navigation (wix)?

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-navigation

Using react-native-navigation https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation i am able to replace the burger icon for the drawer. However, I can't replace the back button using the same method.

I have tried setting the button on the constructor but to no avail:

```
constructor(props)
{
    super(props)

    this.props.navigator.setTitle({
        title: 'Settings'
    });

    Icon.getImageSource('back', 24, 'orange').then(backIcon => {
        props.navigator.setButtons({
            leftButtons: [
                {
                    icon: backIcon,
                    id: 'back'
                }]
        })
    });

}
```

Has anyone figured out how to set a custom icon for the back button?

---

OS: Mac OS Sierra

react-native: "0.44.0"

react-native-navigation: "^1.1.79"

Platform: Android

Answer (score 1):

As of v1, there are a few id's that are reserved by RNN. When any of these id's is used, the custom icon passed to the button params is ignored.
[From the docs](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/adding-buttons-to-the-navigator?id=android-left-button) - four button types are supported by default without the need to provide an icon.
You can use any other id and that code should work, but you'll need to handle the button press your self (call pop from `onNavigatorEvent`)

Answer (score -1):

set navigator buttons in push and showModal functions like this:

```
this.props.navigator.push({
            screen: screenName,
            animationType: 'slide-horizontal',
            navigatorButtons: {
                rightButtons: [
                    this.rightBtn
                ],
                leftButtons: [
            {
                icon: backIcon,
                id: 'back'
            }],
                animated: true
            }
        });
```